# Cannot autowire service AbstractController::setContainer() ContainerInterface does not exists

Tags: symfony, shopware6

I'm currently trying to update my Shopware 6 plugin to Version 6.5. This new version update, increased the php and internal Symfony version. With this, I receive the following error when I try to initialize the plugin:

```
Cannot autowire service "**\Controller\*ProductController": argument "$container" of method
"Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController::setContainer()" references
interface "Psr\Container\ContainerInterface" but no such service exists.
Available autowiring aliases for this interface are: "$parameterBag".
```

I use a abstract class for my controller:

```php
use Shopware\Core\System\SystemConfig\SystemConfigService;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

abstract class AMyController extends AbstractController
{

    public function __construct(private readonly SystemConfigService $systemConfigService)
    {
    }
//...
}
```

My controller:

```php
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository;
use Shopware\Core\System\SystemConfig\SystemConfigService;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\RequestCriteriaBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

#[Route(defaults: ['_routeScope' => ['api']])]
class MyProductController extends AMyController 
{

    public function __construct(
        private readonly EntityRepository $orderRepository,
        private readonly EntityRepository $orderLineItemRepository,
        private readonly EntityRepository $productRepository,
        private readonly RequestCriteriaBuilder $requestCriteriaBuilder,
        private readonly SystemConfigService $systemConfigService
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($systemConfigService);
    }
//...
}
```

In my `services.xml` (Resources/config/services.xml) file I have this service registered like this:

```
    <services>
        <service
                id="Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface"
                alias="service_container"
        />

        <service id="MyPluginName\Controller\MyProductController" public="true">
            <argument type="service" id="order.repository"/>
            <argument type="service" id="order_line_item.repository"/>
            <argument type="service" id="product.repository"/>
            <argument type="service" id="Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\RequestCriteriaBuilder"/>
            <argument type="service" id="Shopware\Core\System\SystemConfig\SystemConfigService"/>

            <call method="setContainer">
                <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>
            </call>
        </service>
```

`composer.json`

```json
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyPrefix\\MyPluginName\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "shopware/core": ">=v6.5.0",
        "shopware/administration": ">=v6.5.0"
    }

}
```

Versions used:

- Shopware 6.5.2.1
- symfony 6.3.0
- php 8.1.20

What I did so far:

- I used the code refactor tool, and now use the Route Annotations `#[Route(defaults: ['_routeScope' => ['api']])]`
- I used the services.xml file to manually define all services
- Cleared cache with `./bin/console cache:clear`

Comment: Symfony version? The error message implies that autowire is trying to wire your controller instead using your services.xml.  Often this is due to a name mismatch though that seems unlikely in this case.  If I had to guess your bundle's extension is not getting called and thus services.xml is not being loaded.

Comment: @Cerad I'm using Shopware 6.5.2.1, symfony 6.3.0, php 8.1.20. Will add this to the post.

Comment: Have you verified that services.xml is even being loaded? And if your main app is using autowire at all then you might need to exclude src/MyPrefix from the app services file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this behaviour by specifically loading the config file:

```
class MyPlugin extends Plugin
{

    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        parent::build($container);

        $loader = new XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/Core/Content/DependencyInjection'));
        $loader->load('controller.xml'); // same content as my services.xml
    }
}
```

It's important that the service definitions include the following tag:

```
<service id="MyPluginName\Controller\MyProductController" public="true">
  <!-- all arguments ... -->
  <call method="setContainer">
     <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>
  </call>
</service>
```

The `services.xml` indeed wasn't loaded before.